# Connect to pgadmin client through reverse proxy

Tags: postgresql, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres Database in private subnet on AWS and I want to connect to AWS.

So i create an ec2 with httpd (Apache) as a reverse proxy in public subnet in order to forward my request to RDS database.

User -> pgadmin client -> Reverse proxy on 443 -> RDS.

As information, i can open only 443 and 80 on public subnet.

my Apache configuration :

```
ProxyPass /rds  http://rds-link.compute.amazonaws.com:5432
ProxyPassReverse /rds  http://rds-link.compute.amazonaws.com:5432
```

in Postgres pgadmin (my laptop) I tried to connect to database using https://link-of-reverse-proxy/rds as host , but its not wokring.
i receive the error : could not translate host name to address

Did i miss something ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your EC2 server has access to RDS. You should grant your EC2 server to connect on 5432 to RDS on security group config.

I personally don't install an apache on proxy EC2 server. I open a tunnel via my EC2 server and map 5432 port to my local.

```
ssh ec2-user@my.ec2.server.ip -L 5432:rdshost.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

Comment: The problem is that i can't use SSH directly to this instance. I have a bastion which is controlled by another department

Comment: So did you check security group config?

Comment: in fact, I can't update the security group and open the ssh to my @IP, i really have a limited access

Comment: You don't have to SSH, that was a suggestion. But you have to update security group as I know. Otherwise your reverse proxy server will not have access to your database.

Comment: In fact, i can only update the security group in order to open a communication between the proxy and RDS, but i can't open the SSH directly from my IP to the proxy